# rmarkdown doesn't display tables as interactive

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When executing a chunk, the output isn't displayed as an interactive table. My best guess is that it has something to do with knitr and/or rmarkdown:

```
output: html_document
```

```
require("knitr")
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "C:/...")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE)
```

---

The output isn't interactive but:

```
[1] row      col      expected actual
```

I tried reinstalling r without success.

rmarkdown 2.5

knitr 1.3

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: What packages are you using to create this table? we will need more code to help find a solution.

Comment: Sorry. Here are the packages I used: `library(httr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(skimr)
library(stringr)
library(readxl) library(openxlsx)`